# MSBuild command line - add dll reference

Tags: c#, dll, msbuild, reference

I use a makefile to compile my C# project.
In this makefile, I create a library tools.dll calling csc.exe, OK.

Now, I want to use this .dll in my project.
For some reasons, I have to use MSBuild.exe which use .csproj file.
In .csproj file I added this section :

```
<Reference Include="TOOLS">
  <HintPath>C:\Gen\Lib\TOOLS.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

That's works fine !

But my question is :
How can I add tools.dll reference from MSBuild command line ?

I need that, to call MSBuild.exe in makefile and give it the path of tools.dll file

Comment: Are you asking how you can reference assemblies which names/locations are not known upfront but are build in the same buildstep and referenced by the same build script? Otherwise you just did....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually you can.

```
<Project InitialTargets="ValidateToolsDllExists" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<Target Name="ValidateToolsDllExists">
    <Error
        Text=" The ToolsDllPath property must be set on the command line."
        Condition="'$(ToolsDllPath)' == ''" />
    <Error
        Text=" The ToolsDllPath property must be set to the full path to tools.dll."
        Condition="!Exists('$(ToolsDllPath)')" />
</Target>

<PropertyGroup>
     <!-- Default path to tools.dll -->
     <ToolsDllPath Condition="'$(ToolsDllPath)'==''">C:\Gen\Lib\TOOLS.dll</ToolsDllPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
     <Reference Include="Tools">
        <HintPath>$(ToolsDllPath)</HintPath>
     </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

to build your project with custom **tools.dll** use this command line:

```
msbuild.exe yourproject.csproj /p:Configuration=Release;Platform=AnyCPU /p:ToolsDllPath=C:\Gen\Tools\bin\Release\Tools.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, msbuild only works on project files, which already contain all needed information.

If you want to kick off the compile yourself and have full control, use csc.exe directly, there you can use the `/r:assembly` switch.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like to use csc.exe but it can't compile .xaml files, and I have some .xaml file in my windows phone 7 project. Do you know how I can parse .xaml files to .cs files as MSBuild do ?

Comment: That's a completely different question.  Start another one.

Comment: From a quick google: you can't. XAML transformation isn't available from command line apperently.