# msbuild ignores passed ReferencePath

Tags: c#, jenkins, xamarin.android, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

**Summary:**

I'm passing `/p:ReferencePath` to `msbuild`, when building a Xamarin.Android project. This does work with `Visual Studio 2017`, but not with `Visual Studio 2019`.

**In detail:**

I have two projects:

- Xamarin.Forms (with main class library, iOS and Android project underneath)
- Class library

The Xamarin.Forms project is referencing the class library via `HintPath` directly in `Debug` build. On the build server (Jenkins) things work differently (release build) and the library is build separately. Therefore I use `ReferencePath` to overwrite the stored `HintPath` and reference the class library (dll) on the Jenkins server, which was previously build.

The failing build command looks like this

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild" 
    TestJenkins/TestJenkins/TestJenkins.Android/TestJenkins.Android.csproj 
    /p:Configuration=Release /p:ReferencePath=C:\Jenkins\workspace\TestMSBuild\MPL1.0 
    /t:PackageForAndroid /t:Build /v:diag
```

I left out the other parts, because they do work. When reading the output log I noticed the following, when building with `Visual Studio 2019`:

- the `ResolveAssemblyReference` task doesn't list the passed `ReferencePath` under `SearchPaths=` for the `Android` build, but it is listed for the class library build (the main library for the `Xamarin.Forms` project and not the separate class library)
- one warning MSB3245
- multiple error CS0246

On another Jenkins machine there is `Visual Studio 2017` installed and the same code, the same scripts does work without an error. So the question is, what's the difference. Lately, I upgraded to `.NET Standard`. Perhaps I forgot something?

What I've tried:

- set up a similar test project, but here it fails with error CS0103
- use hard coded link to the dll with `BeforeResolveReferences` and this does work, but that is only a hack (continous integration should not work that way)
- [adding `ReferencePath` in csproj](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54135125/426227) in Android project, but still the same errors
- changed `Copy local` in the Android project
- `Visual Studio 2019` does build the project on the Jenkins server, if I update the references and use hard-coded links
- read the diagnostic log (140k lines)
- read the manual, but the use of `RerencePath` is not really explained
- many more ...

**Question:**

As you can see I'm using the build tools of `Visual Studio 2019`, but I don't know what has changed to `Visual Studio 2017 Build Tools`. Am I calling `msbuild` wrong? Does `/p:ReferencePath` works different than I expect? Can someone give me a hint to find the cause for this?

**Edit (1):**

Now I found the following out: The `CS0246` error point to lines in my Android project, where a `using` statement is made: e.g. `using MyClassLibrary.Component.Feature;`.

The `MSB3245` warning seams to occur if the `HintPath` in the Android project can't be resolved.

Back to the `using` statement: I have an interface defined my external class library. A class in the Android project implements this. E.g.

Code in external class library:

```
public interface ITextService
{
    string GetText();
}
```

Code in Android project:

```
using SomeLibrary; // error CS0246
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(TestJenkins.Droid.TextService))]
namespace TestJenkins.Droid
{
    public class TextService : ITextService // error CS0246
    {
        public string GetText()
        {
            return SomeLibrary.ServiceClass.NativeKey;
        }
    }
}
```

The question still is, why can't the reference from the Android project be resolved?

**Edit (2):**

For me that must be a [bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/346169/paramater-referencepath-ignored-when-net-standard.html) in `msbuild` with VS2019 or a behavior change. So I thought I can combine [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066853/msbuild-command-line-add-dll-reference) with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19309880/using-assemblysearchpaths-in-csproj-files):

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" InitialTargets="ValidateToolsDllExists" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="ValidateToolsDllExists">
    <Error
        Text=" The ToolsDllPath property must be set on the command line."
        Condition="'$(ToolsDllPath)' == ''" />
    <Error
        Text=" The ToolsDllPath property must be set to the full path to tools.dll."
        Condition="!Exists('$(ToolsDllPath)')" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="BeforeResolveReferences">
    <CreateProperty
      Value="$(ToolsDllPath);$(AssemblySearchPaths)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Value"
        PropertyName="AssemblySearchPaths" />
    </CreateProperty>
  </Target>
  <!-- ... -->
</Project>
```

But passing `/p:ToolsDllPath=C:\path\to\my\dll` to `msbuild` still throws the `CS0246` error.

Comment: You mentioned that you tried adding the ReferencePath to the .proj file , did you made sure that the property group is evaluated. Meaning it's not under a condition that evaluates to false in the build machine.

Comment: Also make sure the target platform of the source assembly and the dependent assembly are compatible and valid.

Comment: @emaditaj: Do you mean the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com) or a [paid support ticket](https://support.microsoft.com/supportforbusiness/productselection?sapId=5e4af7f3-a372-88ed-13a8-435150045599)? Do you know if it is a bug if you still have to pay for the support? What are the prices for one ticket or does this get billed by hours?

Comment: @Soundararajan: I've added [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54135125/426227) to my main XF .csproj file (but not to the Android csproj). There is no condition, the whole node looks like this: `<PropertyGroup><TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework><NeutralLanguage>en</NeutralLanguage><AssemblySearchPaths>$(AssemblySearchPaths);$(ReferencePath);</AssemblySearchPaths></PropertyGroup>`. Do you mean the settings in the *Configuration Manager*? Here the same configuration (*Debug/Release*) and Platform (*Any CPU*) is set. *Target framework* is always `.NET Standard 2.0`.